# RAG + SQLDataBaseChain Error + Sql not getting generated properly

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I am creating a RAG system with SQLDataBaseChain as shown below, vector db contains few shots examples for the Question/SQL/Answer pair as shown below using Palm2 model
[image]

So many Query are working fine however for few as I am getting the below error , extra word sql is causing the error-
[image]

Anybody knows how to fix this error ?

Thanks,
Aritra